# Python Tkinter display the name with Hi in front of it

Tags: python, tkinter

- Hello I'm a few weeks into python and I'm now starting learning tkinter. The button should have the text Say hello and when the user clicks the button, the bottom label should display the name with Hi in front of it. However I cannot get the label to display "Hi {name}". Could someone help me?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

def process_name():
    """Do something with the name (in this case just print it)"""

    global name_entry
    print("Hi {}".format(name.get()))
    

def main():
    """Set up the GUI and run it"""

    global name_entry
    window = Tk()
    
    name_label = Label(window, text='Enter name a name below:')
    name_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
    name_entry = Entry(window)
    name_entry.grid(row=1, column=3)
    button = Button(window, text='Say hello', command=process_name, padding=10)
    button.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)
 
    window.mainloop()

        
main()
```

- I've tried using set() but it doesn't display.
  Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO :). When running your code, I can see a button with 'say hello' text, an Entry box and a label which says "enter name a name below." But as you described, there is no label BELOW the button. You need to clarify what exactly do you wish to update.

Comment: That changes the button acw. How would you add a label under the button?

Comment: Create an empty label below the button and update its text inside `process_name()`.

Comment: I wasnt able to recreate it. Are you able to write it out for me? Thank you for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for your needs. Make sure to read the code comments to understand what I did properly.

Few points though,

- Not recommended to use wildcard import like `from tkinter import *` . The reason is simple. both `tkinter` and `tkinter.ttk` have common classes and functions like `Button`, `Label` and more. It becomes ambiguous for interpreter to decide which ones to use.
- use `.config()` or `.configure()` to update labels, buttons, entries or text widgets in `tkinter`. Like I did in code below.

## Your code modified

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

def process_name():
    """Do something with the name (in this case just print it)"""

    global name_entry # this will print hi {name} to terminal.
    print("Hi {}".format(name_entry.get()))

    global nameLabel # to change'the label with hi{name} text below the button.
    nameLabel.configure(text=f'Hi {name_entry.get()}')

    
    

def main():
    """Set up the GUI and run it"""

    global name_entry, nameLabel
    window = Tk()
    
    name_label = Label(window, text='Enter name a name below:')
    name_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
    name_entry = Entry(window)
    name_entry.grid(row=1, column=3)
    button = Button(window, text='Say hello', command=process_name, padding=10)
    button.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=2)

    # I defined a label BELOW the button to show how to change
    nameLabel = Label(window, text=' ') # an empty text Label
    nameLabel.grid(row=2)
 
    window.mainloop()

        
main()
```